# Execution does not await for condition

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm trying to get the result of a method to use in a different call.

The var 'AuthToken' will be set with an event, max 500ms after I connect to the `authSocket`

I tried using async/await, but when stepping through the debugger in VS2017 the code continues to

`gameSocket = new Client_TBDGame(...)`

before `authSocket.GetAuthToken(...)` even returns.

If anyone can take a look it would be awesome! Maybe there exists a completely different solution for my problem?

I have the following code:

```
public static async Task<string> Init(string _ip) 
{
    if (!IsHostUp(_ip)) 
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Cannot connect to Server!");
        return "ERROR_SERVER_UNREACHABLE";
    }

    authSocket = new Client_Authenticate(_ip, Settings.SERVER_PORT);
    token = await authSocket.GetAuthToken().ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Connect to /game endpoint
    gameSocket = new Client_TBDGame(_ip, Settings.SERVER_PORT, token);
    return "SUCCESS";
}
```

Client_Authenticate

```
public async Task<string> GetAuthToken() 
{
    // Cancel after 15 tries and return "ERROR_TIMEOUT"
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) 
    {
        if (AuthToken != null || AuthToken != "") 
            return AuthToken;
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }

    return "ERROR_TIMEOUT";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the code continues to `gameSocket...` before `GetAuthToken` even returns.

No, sorry, that's not possible. The code posted will not reach `gameSocket` before `GetAuthToken` returns. If you're seeing that, it's possible that you have multiple calls to `Init`.

That said, the `Task.Delay` polling loop is a poor approach. This is a "signal" of sorts, so I'd recommend using `TaskCompletionSource<string>` instead of `string`. When the auth token arrives, call `TrySetResult(...)`, and your consuming code can look like this:

```
authSocket = new Client_Authenticate(_ip, Settings.SERVER_PORT);
token = await authSocket.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
```